# Colorbar With subplots

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

How do I get colorbar when there is a figure and two subplots . I want separate colorbar for all subplots .
For Example

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.set_title('PC')
ax2.set_title('MC')
im=ax1.imshow(topo.sim.PC.activity,interpolation='nearest')
im1=ax2.imshow(topo.sim.MC.activity,interpolation='nearest')
```

I tried `plt.colorbar()` and `ax1.colorbar()` as well. Doesn't seem working.
I have animation on both the images in later part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.colorbar(ax=ax1)`?

Comment: yes I tried after both `imshow()` . Gives me an error .

Comment: With more than 1000 reputation on Stack Overflow, you should know that "gives an error" is never enough information:)

Comment: I am sorry ! Have come back after long time . It gives me the error saying  'No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation' . seems it cant find appropriate image to map with colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite your code as follows, then it will work. When using colorbar, you need to specify in which axis you want to put it. This is easy to figure out when looking at the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_image.html) in the matplotlib gallery.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.set_title('PC')
ax2.set_title('MC')
im=ax1.imshow(topo.sim.PC.activity,interpolation='nearest')
im1=ax2.imshow(topo.sim.MC.activity,interpolation='nearest')

plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)
plt.colorbar(im1, ax=ax2)
```

If the colour bar is too big, you may want to use shrink kwarg.